# Layout don't keep when printing page Zend Framework 2 Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, printing, zend-framework2

I need to print the following page :

[image: Page to print]

But the result is not as expected :

[image: Result of print]

It seems like my bootstrap css is not used when I print the webpage.

**This is the HTML code of my page :**

```
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Route Du Drive</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <!-- Le styles -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&amp;subset=all" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/metronic/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/metronic/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/metronic/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
<link href="/metronic/global/css/components-md.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/metronic/global/css/plugins-md.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/metronic/pages/css/login-4.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/global.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Scripts -->        
    </head>
    <body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <header>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Commande N°O001</h3>
            <h4>Boulangerie Ange Oceanis</h4>
            <h4>1 Rue de la Côte de Nacre</h4>
            <h4>44600 Saint-Nazaire</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>        <div class="col-xs-3"><h3>Commande archivée</h3></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3>Nom du client</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <h3 class="text-center">Articles commandés</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Check</th>
                        <th>Référence</th>
                        <th>Dénomination</th>
                        <th>Prix unitaire</th>
                        <th>Quantité</th>
                        <th>Cout</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>PAIN</td>
                        <td>Baguette de pain</td>
                        <td>0.93 €</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>8.37 €</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td><b>Total commande</b></td>
                        <td>8.37 €</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
           <a href="../manageshop/boulangerieangeoceanis" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Retour à la page précédente</a>
      </div>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/metronic/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/metronic/global/plugins/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/metronic/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/metronic/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/metronic/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/metronic/global/plugins/backstretch/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/metronic/global/scripts/app.min.js"></script>
```

How can I print the page with the original styling? 
Does someone have an idea what is causing the problem?

Comment: styles on printing pages is different.

Comment: How can I change it on zend ?

Comment: Try to check your page print preview if it displays the same to your page

Comment: and also how do you call the bootstrap css? can you include it also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to locate the following line:

```
<link href="/metronic/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and change it to

```
<link href="/metronic/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The changes is on the `media="screen"` to `media="all"`. This change will ensure that the same styling for both displaying the page on the screen as well as on your print.

Read more on the `media` attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp) or [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link).